# how to change woocommerce shop page details?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've used a snippet to display the weight of jewellery in shop page of woocommerce. I've inserted the snippet in function.php file. But its displaying the weight below add to cart button. It must be displayed above the button.

here is the snippet

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_product_dimensions_loop', 20 );

function bbloomer_show_product_dimensions_loop() {
global $product;
$dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();
if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
  echo '<div class="dimensions">';
  echo '<br><b>Weight:</b> ' . $product->get_weight() . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' );
  
  echo '</div>';        
}
}
```

[image: here is the sample output]

the weight must be printed above the add to cart button, what i've to change here.

Comment: Try it by changing the priority from 20 to 9 - `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_product_dimensions_loop', 9 );`

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'bbloomer_show_product_dimensions_loop', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_show_product_dimensions_loop( $html, $product ) {

    $weight = '';

    $dimensions = $product->get_dimensions();

    if ( ! empty( $dimensions ) ) {
        $weight .= '<div class="dimensions">';
        $weight .= '<br><b>Weight:</b> ' . $product->get_weight() .
            esc_html( get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) );
        $weight .= '</div>';
    }

    return $weight . $html;
}
```

You have to use the filter tag `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` and prepend your weight component HTML like this. Since it's filter hook no need to echo the output just return the output HTML the tag `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` will handle that.

Based on my own blog tutorial: [How To Add Quantity Input In Shop Page](https://www.vijayan.in/how-to-add-quantity-input-in-shop-page/)

Visit [source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php#L24) if you want to learn how this filter `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` works internally.

Comment: @cbra if any improvement in the answer if you need please let me know, hope this resolved your issue as this hook directly interact with the add to cart button

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of flex css for example:

```
    .itemxyz{display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
    .itemxyz .desc{order: 1;}
    .itemxyz .price{order: 2;}
    .itemxyz .btn{ order: 4;}
    .itemxyz .weight{ order: 3;}
```